# adding button to the tcl gui

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I created a gui with many tabs, i would like to add button to the tab1.

However i am not good at tcl, Could someone help how to add button to the TCL gui?

Regards

```
toplevel .test
wm transient .test.
set pw [ttk::panedwindow .test.pw -orient vertical]
set nb [ttk::notebook $pw.nb]
foreach i {1 2 3 4} {$nb add [frame $nb.f$i] -text tab$i}
set fTkCon [frame $pw.fTkConContainer -container 1]
$pw add $nb
$pw add $fTkCon
pack $pw -fill both -expand
#add button here# ::hwtk::button  -text "Text Button" -help "Text only"
```

Comment: Where do you want the button to be added? Inside which widget or tab?

Comment: this code creates 4 tab, i just want to learn how can i add a button to tab1. Then i can do it to the others .

Comment: Hi Donal i saw on your profile, you are on TCL core team. I am trying to learn tcl for developing some fea applications. Could you please tell me which resources will be better for starting TCL?

Comment: This is not all code. Please add the pieces missing to make it run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the foreach loop, you created 4 frames ($nb.f1 through $nb.f4). To add a button in tab1, you should normally create the widget as a child of the respective frame. You then need to use a geometry manager to control where the widget will appear. When just starting with GUIs, grid is probably the easiest choice.

```
ttk::button $nb.f1.b1 -text Button! -command {puts Pressed!}
grid $nb.f1.b1 -padx 5 -pady 5
```

Note: When doing this in an interactive session, you will probably have to resize the window and move the sash of the paned window to see the button.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the code a little to make it run:

```
package require Tk

ttk::notebook .nb
pack .nb
foreach i {1 2 3 4} {
    .nb add [button .nb.f$i -text "Button $i"] -text tab$i
}
```

Notice to add a button to a tab, I exchanged the creation of `frame` in the notebook add command to creation of a `button`.